# request.form.get returns None instead of input

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm creating a game in which someone inputs a word (that produces a search) and you have to guess what word it was by the results produced.
It works by getting the word inputed by player 1 (input1) and comparing it to your guess (input2).

When the user submits the input1, my python code gets it and stores it.
But when the second player inputs input2 and submits, the input1 is overriden and request.form.get = None (although it gets input2 perfectly fine).

What is happening and how could I fix it? Thank you (PS: I know this looks like a lot of code, but most of it is for context)

HMTL

```
<h4 id='playern' style='color:grey; margin:20px;'>Player 1</h4>


<!-- Search -->
<div id='cont1' style='display:flex; flex-direction:column; justify-content:center'>
    <p>Choose search for <em>Player 2</em> to guess.</p>
    <form id='form1' action='/multi' method='post'>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input name='input1' id="input1" autofocus autocomplete='off' placeholder="cats, face..." type="text">
            <button id='input-btn' type='submit'>Submit</button>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>


<!--iframe-->
<div style='height:70%; width:100%; overflow:hidden;margin:10px 0px 50px 0px; position: sticky; display:flex; justify-content:center; border-style:none'>
    <iframe id='innerSpace' style="display:none;height:200%;width:60vw;margin-top:-120px;border-style:none;" title="Results"></iframe>
</div>


<!-- Guess -->
<div id='cont2' style='display:none; height: max-content; width:100%; position: sticky; border-style:none'>
    <h5>What is the search for these results?</h5>
    <form action='/multi' method='post'>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <input name='input2' id='input2' type='text'  autofocus autocomplete='off' placeholder='Guess'>
            <button id='guess-btn' type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
  let is = document.getElementById('innerSpace');
  let input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
  let input2 = document.getElementById('input2');

  let playern = document.getElementById('playern');
  let cont1 = document.getElementById('cont1');
  let cont2 = document.getElementById('cont2');

  let spacer = document.getElementById('spacer');

  input1.addEventListener('change', searchFor);
  function searchFor() {
    //create constant variable with the value of input1
    const inp = input1;
    playern.innerHTML = 'Player 2';
    playern.style.marginTop = '0px';
    // hide first form and show the second one
    cont1.style.display = 'none';
    cont2.style.display = 'flex';
    cont2.style.flexDirection = 'column';
    cont2.style.justifyContent = 'center';
    cont2.style.alignItems = 'center';
    spacer.style.display ='none';
    is.style.display = 'flex';
    // search results
    let query = encodeURIComponent(input1.value);
    is.src = `https://search.givewater.com/serp?qc=images&q=weirdest+${query}`;
    // when user submits guess
    input2.addEventListener('change', function(){
        // trying to override None value by replacing with const value
        input1.value = inp.value;
        // tryin to re-submit input1
        document.getElementById("form1").submit();
    });
  }
```

Python

```
@app.route('/multi', methods =['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def multiplayer():

    #If user got here from link
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('multiplayer.html')

    #If user inputed something
    if request.method == 'POST':

        global inp
        inp = request.form.get('input1')

        #this stops the whole page from loading before user submits a guess
        while not request.form.get('input2'):
            #wait
            print('.', end='')
            time.sleep(1)
            #if guess exists
            if request.form.get('input2'):
                break

        ui = inp

        #Get guess
        guess = request.form.get('input2')

        #Get User id
        userId = session['user_id']

        #Get current score from user (and id)
        rows = db.execute('SELECT * FROM scores WHERE user_id = ?', userId)

        #if this user hasn't played yet
        ##add them to the table with a score of 0
        if not rows:
            db.execute('INSERT INTO scores (user_id, score) VALUES (?, ?)', userId, 0)
            rows = db.execute('SELECT * FROM scores WHERE user_id = ?', userId)

        #Get score of current user
        points = rows[0]['score']


        #If correct guess, increase points by 1
        if guess == inp:
            points += 1
            #Update score
            db.execute('UPDATE scores SET score = ? WHERE user_id = ?', points, userId )
            #copy to another variable
            w = inp
            g = guess
            s = points
            return render_template('results.html', title = 'Correct!', t1 = 'The search was', word = w, t2 = 'Your guess was', guess = g, score = s)
        #If wrong guess
        else:
            w = inp
            g = guess
            s = points
            return render_template('results.html', title = 'Incorrect', t1 = 'The search was', word = w, t2 = 'Your guess was', guess = g, score = s)
```

Comment: So you can get both inputs when they are submitted? But the issue is you lose the first input after the second one (the *guessing* input), correct?

Comment: @JakeJackson yes, when I submit the first one, it's fine; but when I submit the second one, the first one becomes none and the second one is fine.

On javascript the values are there, it's the python that is failing on getting, I think

Comment: Since you are storing the first input into `inp`, why is it an issue?

Comment: I don't know...when I submit the second one, python makes the `request.form.get` again but this time, it returns `None`, for some reason. I tried to override that `None` value by storing the value of input1 in a constant value in js, but the value doesn't pass to python...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a global variable for `inp` and `guess`, use the session cookie instead:

```
from flask import session

...

session['inp'] = request.form.get('input1')

...

session['guess'] = request.form.get('input2')

...

if session['inp'] == session['guess]:
   # do stuff
```

Storing values in a global variable is not the thing you want to be doing here; it doesn't behave the way you think it would, and it isn't very practical.